# Deleting formula sources without destroying formula output, using Numbers for Mac

Tags: mac, numbers

I would like to delete the source column for a formula in Numbers 3.2.2, without destroying values in the formula's output column. Specifically, I have a column of "Last, First" names, which I parse by comma and output to two separate columns, "Last" and "First". How can I delete the "Last, First" column without destroying the output values in the "Last" and "First" columns?

An image of the current state of things is shown in the link after this paragraph. The formula used to generate the First Name column is shown for the "Example, A" entry. I'd like to lock the output column's values in place, such that they no longer draw on the source column, "Full Name". [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select the columns with the data that you want to preserve.
2. Choose Copy from the Edit menu (or hit <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
3. Choose Paste Formula Results from the Edit menu (or hit <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

You should end up with just the results of the formula.

Comment: Shift ⇧+Command ⌘+V is important. I tried just Command ⌘+V and it didn't work.